# Readfile returns an empty file

Tags: php, file, download, readfile

I have this code to force a download, `$file` is a **url** of a existing .jpg, .png or .pdf file (I made sure it exists)

```
 <?php
    $file = $_REQUEST['file'];
    $file_extension = end(explode('.', $file));
    $file_name = end(explode('/', $file));
    switch ($file_extension) {
        case 'jpg':
            header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file_name);
            header('Pragma: no-cache');
            readfile($file);
            break;
        case 'png':
            header('Content-Type: image/png');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file_name);
            header('Pragma: no-cache');
            readfile($file);
            break;
        case 'pdf':
            header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file_name);
            header('Pragma: no-cache');
            readfile($file);
            break;
    }
```

But it's downloading an empty (0KB) file (with the correct name)

Any thought about what may be happening?

Comment: Did you make sure that `$file` is an existing one? As in: accessible from your current location? I.e. if `$file` is `dir/file.jpg`, but your script is running in `/something/x/`, while dir `dir` is in `/something/x/y/dir`, the path won't resolve. You can do a quick `var_dump(file_exists($file)); exit;` to find out.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my question, i made sure they exist (it's a working image/pdf URL)

Comment: If you try var_dump(file_get_contents($file)) you can get the content?

Comment: @FrancescoMineo that's odd.. it prints out `bool(false)`

Comment: Why not redirecting the request to the URI? `readfile()` is not primarily meant to read remote files, it's just a bonus.

Comment: @AmigoJack they're not remote, but it's a URL format. The client wants to force the download, not opening the content.

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet Have you tried with different url? ( I mean different domain )

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet your url contains GET variables?

Comment: Yes, the url (I edited the domain) is like: `https://website.com/download.php?file=https://website.com/wp-uploads/2018/11/luxury-hotel.jpg`

Comment: Going from the file system thru HTTP is remote, no matter if anything afterwards goes back to the system you're coming from. Your approach takes needless routes and encounters one of its pitfalls. Deliver the local file instead.

Comment: for testing purpose, instead of $_REQUEST['file'] put $file = 'https://website.com/download.php?file=https://website.com/wp-uploads/2018/11/luxury-hotel.jpg'; and check.

Comment: Also https://website.com/wp-uploads/2018/11/luxury-hotel.jpg , Image is not there

Comment: @ShivendraSingh (I edited the domain) as it's a customer webiste, but the one that i'm trying it does work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since file_get_contents() return null too, your problem is probably a setting in the php.ini configuration.

The parameter **allow_url_fopen** must be **On**.

Comment: Sorry but https://website.com/download.php is the file where this code is, so it's not part of the download file

Comment: Please check in your PHP INI if you have the option 'allow_url_fopen' disabled. You have to enable it.

Comment: i think that must be it.. i will check and let you know

Comment: That was it, if you want to edit the answer so i can accept it ;)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are missing a Content-Length header.

Try this:

```
$file = $_REQUEST['file'];
$file_extension = end(explode('.', $file));
$file_name = end(explode('/', $file));

switch ($file_extension) {
    case 'jpg':
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        break;
    case 'png':
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file_name);
        break;
    case 'pdf':
        header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
        break;
}

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file_name);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

// You may want to add this headers too (If you don't want the download to be resumable - I think).
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');

// And you may consider flushing the system's output buffer if implicit_flush is turned on in php.ini.
flush();

// If you have the file locally.
readfile($file);

// Otherwise,
echo file_get_contents($file); // You should have allow_url_include on in php.ini
```

Didn't get to try it, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but the problem persisits

Comment: If it doesn't work, then you may want to check the file itself. Are you sure the file exists in the same directory as your script? Because that's what your original code implies.

Comment: I think the problem is that even it's in the same host, is not a path but an URL

Comment: I will update my answer now to handle such case scenario.

Comment: Its not working because `file_get_contents($file)` returns false.. and the downvote it's not mine